# Proof using the rule of product or multiplication rule of combinatorics.

Tags: combinatorics

Assume that  set $A$ has $r$ elements, and set $B$ has $n$ elements (both of them are finite and not empty sets), I need to proof using the rule of product or multiplication principle of combinatorics, that the number of mappings of $A$ in $B$ is $n^r$.

I am realy lost on this one!
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

try numbering elements of A as $a_1, a_2 \ldots a_r$, then your events will be $a_i$ maps to $b_k$. there are r events, each with n possible outcomes, so you're done by the multiplication principle (and r-steps induction)